# How to add nested dialog in bot builder / how to add new dialog based on the c# code condition

Tags: c#, botframework

Am trying to add new dialog based on the condition, by default we mention the dialog to run and it contains multiple activities that is working fine but in between any of the activity needs to add new dialog based on the condition that we written then how to add that dialog .

Main dialog -> { AskNamestep, AskGenderstep{here in this method i will put some condition like if male go to another dialog else continue same dialog}, AskMessage}.

am attaching snapshot please give me some solutions.

[This is the main Dialog Onturn method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nETWL.png)

[So this is the another class created for nested Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oikUF.png)

Comment: Can you please elaborate it bit. Because from the image i see nesteddialog inherites IBot and not ComponentDialog.

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

You call `turnContext.BeginDialogAsync(<nameOfTheDialog>)`, similar to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L63):

```cs
stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), new BookingDetails(), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that, when I've dealt with branching like this, I've usually taken the approach to put each branch in a separate dialog rather than have one branch within the "main" dialog. You can do this, but keep in mind that unless you have some conditions to skip steps, you cannot start this new dialog in the middle. Also, you need to make sure you pass the name and gender to the new dialog or save them to user or conversation state (if the new dialog needs these values).